# decoded pcm sounds weird using decodeAudioData interface in Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, decode, web-audio-api

I use decodeAudioData interface in Web Audio API to decode some aac streams from websocket. The pcms are played by feeding to scriptNode in onprocess callback. However, it is weird between every two stream segments, sounds like a short break off. 
I check the output pcms and find that some datas in front are all zeros. I think that leads to the weird playback effect.
So how can I eliminate that so that I can play the streams smoothly?

Comment: Those are called glitches between the aduio segments.

Comment: Delete the 0s? You can avoid glitching if you set the gain smoothly (10-100ms) to 0 before the audio chunk stops. Otherwise the sinus curve will fall from 1 to 0 which sounds like a glitch.

Comment: I think the occurrence of the gliches betwen pcm chunks from decodeAudioData interface is due to the interface itself. Two aac frame have some kind of relation when they are encoded, decoding the latter one is relied on the previous one. But decodeAudioData does not keep the previous aac chunk's decode information, so the latter aac chunk can't be decoded correctly. Do you think so?